# Looping through DELETE in code vs in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have been struggling with deleting massive quantities of old data from a database.  Each of 5 different tables has as many as 50M rows that need to be deleted.  No single delete statement could handle that quantity of data, so I have to loop through deleting a few at a time.  My question is to whether there is any noticeable performance increase in looping within a stored procedure instead of looping in the application code.  Now for the specifics, I am using DB2 (9.7 CE), and coding in C#.  For my stored procedure I use:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
DROP PROCEDURE myschema.purge_orders_before;
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE PROCEDURE myschema.purge_orders_before (IN before_date TIMESTAMP)
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
P1: BEGIN
    DECLARE no_data SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE deadlock_encountered SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE deadlock_condition CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '40001';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
        SET no_data = 1;

    -- The deadlock_encountered attribute is throw-away,
    -- but a continue handler needs to do something,
    -- i.e., it's not enough to just declare a handler,
    -- it has to have an action in its body.
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR deadlock_condition
        SET deadlock_encountered = 1;

    WHILE (no_data = 0 ) DO
        DELETE FROM 
            (SELECT 1 FROM myschema.orders WHERE date < before_date FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY );
        COMMIT;
    END WHILE;
END P1
@
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
```

Whose approach was unceremoniously lifted from [this thread](http://www.dbmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/ibm-db2/8481/deleting-large-numbers-of-records).  My programmatic approach is as follows:

```
public static void PurgeOrdersBefore( DateTime date ) {
    using ( OleDbConnection connection = DatabaseUtil.GetInstance( ).GetConnection( ) ) {
        connection.Open( );
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand( deleteOrdersBefore, connection );
        command.Parameters.Add( "@Date", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp ).Value = date;
        int rows = 0;
        int loopRows = 0;
        int loopIterations = 0;

        log.Info( "starting PurgeOrdersBefore loop" );
        while ( true ) {
            command.Transaction = connection.BeginTransaction( );
            loopRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery( );
            command.Transaction.Commit( );
            if ( loopRows <= 0 ) {
                break;
            }
            if ( log.IsDebugEnabled ) log.Debug( "purged " + loopRows + " in loop iteration " + loopIterations );

            loopIterations++;
            rows += loopRows;
        }
        if ( log.IsInfoEnabled ) log.Info( "purged " + rows + " orders in " + loopIterations + " loop iterations" );
    }
}
```

I performed a *VERY* primitive test in which I printed a timestamp at the start and finish and broke out of the loop after 10,000 in each.  The outcome of said test was that the stored procedure took slightly over 6 minutes to delete 10,000 rows and the programmatic approach took just under 5 minutes.  Being as primitive as it was, I imagine the only conclusion I can draw is that their is likely going to be very minimal difference in practice and keeping the loop in the C# code allows for much more dynamic monitoring.

All that said, does anyone else have any input on the subject?  Could you explain what kind of hidden benefits I might receive were I to use the stored procedure approach?  In particular, if Serge Rielau keeps an eye on this site, I would love to hear what you have to say (seems to be that he is the ninja all the others refer to when it comes to DB2 nonsense like this...)

-------------- Edit ---------------------

How about an export of some sort followed by a LOAD REPLACE?  Has anyone done that before?  Is there an example that I could follow?  What implications would that have?

Comment: Have you tried running it with `FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY`?

Comment: Are you sure no single DELETE statement can do it?

Comment: @ypercupe, yup, and read on some of the related threads that as you grow from 100 per commit, the performance gain approaches becoming negligible (which my trivial test cases tended to confirm).

Comment: Just trying to run it caused a timeout.  I could try increasing timeout to infinite, but it would just slam the db2 logs to the best of my knowledge (since as a single statement it would be in a single transaction which means it would have to remember all of the rows in order to perform the rollback in case of failure).  It would also lock the table during the entire process which is not going to work and would really suck if it failed after processing for 72 hours and rolled back everything it did....

Comment: How many rows will be _left_ afterwards? Would it work to read the good ones into a temp table, truncate the entire table, and then put the good ones back in?

Comment: @Andrew, i will be left with > 100M rows, so no, cant do that either...

Comment: @Lucas - If you are performing a commit immediately, what about adding the `WITH NO COMMIT` clause to the `DELETE` statement?

Comment: @X-Zero, I do not see that clause as being available on [DB2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000939.html).  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lucas - Sorry, it looks like `NO COMMIT` isn't available - the specific one I listed is basically a "don't hold any locks" value that is probably only available on the iSeries version - the version you would (otherwise) use would be `NC` (so, `WITH NC`), but it doesn't appear to be available for `DELETE` statements... dunno why, though.

Comment: Unless db2 requires you to, I would not use transactions.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus, I take back my comment before (_at least partially_).  After testing as many different approaches as I could find, the best performance came by creating new tables from the records I want to keep, then drop the table and indexes, then rename the keep table and add back the indexes.  This still takes a very long time, but it works and is faster than any other approach I have found.  If you would like to write your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of records to delete is a large fraction of the total, it can be cheaper to copy the *good* records into a temporary table, empty the original table, and copy the temp table back. The optimal way to do this is not consistent across RDBMSes; for example, some support `TRUNCATE` and others do not.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the TOP command.  I assume that you have problems with the size of the log file (which is why you can't just use a Delete from table command).

So you could write your query like so:

```
DELETE TOP 10000
FROM myschema.orders
WHERE date < before_date
```

Then loop over this command until the rows deleted = 0;

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, `TOP` is an Oracle command.  I am using DB2 which uses a slightly different syntax.  I use `FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` and loop around that which I assume accomplishes the same thing.  The problem is, it is deleting records slower than they get added.  I think I am going to have to try something drastic.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware that DB2 syntax was drastically different in this respect, I thought it was something separate to the TOP, obviously no.